# Copy/ Update the primary keys value to another column of the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database table **subscribers** as shown below:

all i need is make the subscriber_number same as subscriber_id.

Eg: If subscriber_id is 261 and subscriber_number is 262 , then i need to make subscriber_number as 261, same as the subscriber id.

Could you please help me with MySQL query to sort this out ?

**UPDATE 1:**

am looking to get MySQL query from you experts here. what i tried was to get the rows where both id and number are different

```
SELECT subscriber_id,subscriber_number 
FROM subscribers 
WHERE subscriber_id <> subscriber_number
```

**Please run the code snippet below to view the table structure with sample data**

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td style="border-right:1px solid #000;border-bottom:1px solid #000;">subscriber_id</td>
      <td style="border-right:1px solid #000;border-bottom:1px solid #000;">subscriber_number</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="border-right:1px solid #000;border-bottom:1px solid #000;">260</td>
      <td style="border-right:1px solid #000;border-bottom:1px solid #000;">260</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="border-right:1px solid #000;border-bottom:1px solid #000;">261</td>
      <td style="border-right:1px solid #000;border-bottom:1px solid #000;">262</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="border-right:1px solid #000;border-bottom:1px solid #000;">262</td>
      <td style="border-right:1px solid #000;border-bottom:1px solid #000;">264</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="border-right:1px solid #000;border-bottom:1px solid #000;">263</td>
      <td style="border-right:1px solid #000;border-bottom:1px solid #000;">272</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="border-right:1px solid #000;border-bottom:1px solid #000;">264</td>
      <td style="border-right:1px solid #000;border-bottom:1px solid #000;">274</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="border-right:1px solid #000;border-bottom:1px solid #000;">266</td>
      <td style="border-right:1px solid #000;border-bottom:1px solid #000;">277</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="border-right:1px solid #000;border-bottom:1px solid #000;">268</td>
      <td style="border-right:1px solid #000;border-bottom:1px solid #000;">282</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="border-right:1px solid #000;border-bottom:1px solid #000;">269</td>
      <td style="border-right:1px solid #000;border-bottom:1px solid #000;">269</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I am not sure how to get this , i tried to get the rows where subscriber_number and subscriber_id are different, before i update. SELECT subscriber_id,subscriber_number FROM `subscribers` WHERE subscriber_id <> subscriber_number

Comment: I don't see any code containing mysql, only a table.

Comment: So you know how to write the select statement and you want to learn how to write the associated update statement? Is this your request?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes i just need to update all the rows where subscriber number is different from subscriber id. As well as i also need to maintain the sequence of the primary keys. For an example, if my scubscriber ids are 61,63,65 i also want to make it as 61,62,63 and make the subscriber number same as subscriber id

Comment: I wonder why you want to do this. Why are there two fields at all, if you want them to always have the same value? Also: why must the numbers be consecutive? An ID is usually just that, some number that you don't care about, and which you only need to join tables. (And you can even decide to build your database without technical IDs and go with the tables' natural keys instead.) A subscriber number on the other hand is a number that uniquely identifies a subscriber (I guess). You already have this. What would you gain from them being consecutive?

Answer (score 2):

The SQL would be

```
UPDATE subscribers SET subscriber_number = subscriber_id
```

This will set the subscriber_number to subscriber_id for every single row in your subscriber-table.

Comment: +1 for your query above. BTW i also need to maintain the subscriber id sequence. For an example, if my scubscriber ids are 61,63,65 i also want to make it as 61,62,63 and make the subscriber number same as subscriber id.

Comment: Usually your ID column would be an identity column, thus you are not able to change it. One solution I could think of would be to have a cursor iterate through each row and update the subscriber_id.. but that seems pretty ugly and I don't see what this could be necessary for.